# Why does the government of the Philippines destroy illegally imported luxury cars instead of using or reselling them?

Tags: philippines

I'm reading the recent news [The Philippines Just Crushed $1.2 Million in Smuggled Luxury Cars, Including a McLaren 620R](https://robbreport.com/motors/cars/philippines-1-2-million-smuggled-car-destruction-mclaren-620r-1234620385/) (which also mentions "In 2018, [the Philippines president] had over $8 million worth of vehicles destroyed") and wondered: why does the government of the Philippines destroy illegally imported luxury cars instead of using or reselling them?

Comment: These cars are probably stolen or otherwise of unknown ownership.

Comment: @KeithMcClary return to owner if known, and sell otherwise?

Comment: Presumably there are reasons they're not supposed to be imported. Those reasons would be undermined if they just imported the cars anyway.

Comment: @user253751  resell them abroad?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the government probably doesn't want to get into the business of selling used cars. Too much hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue is how you would sell the cars and at what price. The usual way to sell seized items is an auction where they would be expected to fetch a low price. This would further undermine the legal market and could even allow the smugglers to recover the cars and still turn a profit. The latter has been cited as the [reason behind the decision to destroy them](https://observers.france24.com/en/asia-pacific/20210622-philippines-luxury-cars-destroyed-strong-warning-smugglers):

> Since 2018, after a directive from Philippino President Rodrigo Duterte, the BOC has opted to destroy smuggled cars rather than auction them, in order to send a strong warning to smugglers as well as prevent them from reclaiming their cars at auction.

Comment: Thanks, interesting I didn't expect that reason. E.g. could set minimum prices, prevent smugglers from partaking auctions, sell abroad to prevent side effects to the local market, etc.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt $1.2 million isn't very much to a government

Comment: @Caleth They seem to be in the habits of distructing cars e.g. still from https://robbreport.com/motors/cars/philippines-1-2-million-smuggled-car-destruction-mclaren-620r-1234620385/ " In 2018, he had over $8 million worth of vehicles destroyed". I'd compare it to the local median wage, which is 12,955 USD/year.

Comment: $10M is still peanuts. it's ~$0.1 per person

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if you could prevent smugglers from taking part in auctions, you could presumably prevent them from smuggling by arresting them.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Please refrain from starting a debate in comments. I answered the question based on what's in the public record. Your objections do not seem very convincing to me but I do not want to discuss them. All that is ultimately irrelevant as the fact the cars were destroyed proves the Filipino authorities did not find any reason convincing enough not to go ahead.

Comment: @Relaxed no worries I was done commenting. No intent to start a debate just making sure I didn't omit something.

Comment: But it would be fairly easy to export the cars and sell them abroad.

Comment: That's a very stupid decision to throw away that money to the garbage. They need to auction the cars. Or sell them abroad.

Comment: https://business.inquirer.net/339468/govt-may-destroy-unsold-luxury-cars-says-dominguez